# Why is ui.Slider throwing "a.toFixed is not a function" error message?

Tags: google-earth-engine, user-interface

I'm trying to get the dates (YYYY) from the first and last images from a collection, let's say, Chirps. Next, I need to use these dates as the min/max parameters in a ui.Slider.

I made sure that i'm parsing Numbers to ui.Slider, even so, it's throwing an error message:

> a.toFixed is not a function
> in , line 6
> in , line 1
> in , line 13

Here goes the code.

```
var CHIRPS = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY");

var range = CHIRPS.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"]);

var firstImg = ee.Number.parse(ee.Date(range.get('min')).format('YYYY')); // 1981 - Number
var lastImg = ee.Number.parse(ee.Date(range.get('max')).format('YYYY')); // 2021 - Number

var sli = ui.Slider({
  min: firstImg,
  max: lastImg,
})

Map.add(sli)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For printing and getting computed **ee.Objects** client-side it is necessary to use `.getInfo()`. So, following modified version of your code works as expected.

```
var CHIRPS = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY");

var range = CHIRPS.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"]);

var firstImg = ee.Number.parse(ee.Date(range.get('min')).format('YYYY')); // 1981 - Number
var lastImg = ee.Number.parse(ee.Date(range.get('max')).format('YYYY')); // 2021 - Number

var sli = ui.Slider({
  min: firstImg.getInfo(),
  max: lastImg.getInfo(),
});

sli.style().set({'backgroundColor': 'E0E0E0',
                  'height': '25px',
                  'border': '5px solid darkgray'
                 });

print(sli);
```

It can be observed in following image:

[image]